# simplifying an equation with fractions

Tags: sequences-and-series, fractions

I am trying to understand a proposed solution posted [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/155385/coin-toss-probability-question-feller) (by user17762) to a problem in Feller's book *Introduction to probability and its applications*, and there is a step that I do not understand. Can anyone please explain what happens here:

[image]

How does the right side follow from the left side?

Thank you so much in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a particular case of the [geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Sum):
$$|r|<1\implies1+r+r^2+r^3+\cdots=\frac1{1-r}.$$

Answer (score 1):

It is a  geometric sum; you can prove that

$\sum_{k=0}^\infty a^k =\frac{1}{1-a}$ for $|a|<1$

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

If $|x|<1$ then :

$$1+x+x^2+... = {1\over 1-x}$$

Answer (score 0):

Working with a geometric series like this, we can attain either a sum to a finite number of terms, or a sum to infinity. In general:
$$S_\infty=\frac{a}{1-r}$$
where $a$ is the first term and $r$ is the multiplier. Here $a=1$ and $r=\frac14$, and so $S_\infty=\frac{1}{1-\frac14}(=\frac43)$